# MongoDB - Java: Not operator and regular expressions

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm having a problem to convert the next line from my java code to mongoDB:

`{ "field1.array": { $not : /\w*(whatever)\w*/ }}`.

I've tried to use this:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria() {
   @Override
   public DBObject getCriteriaObject() {
      return 
         new BasicDBObject("field1.array",
           new BasicDBObject("$not",
           Pattern.compile(regexp)));
  }
};
```

Which does not work because that sends the regular expression as `$regex` function which is not compatible with `$not` operator.

I've tried to negate my regular expression with this: `^((?!my string).)*$`
It does not work neither for my array if I don't specify the array position.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you just lack the "equals" for the pattern. Never tried with DBObject, but using filters it works like this:

```
 collection.find(
    Filters.not(Filters.eq("myField", Pattern.compile("xyz.*")))
 )
```

Comment: What class is that Filters class?

Comment: com.mongodb.client.model.Filters from the mongo java client

Comment: Don't think it will work since it doesn't work converting this code to a mongodb query. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: We use this in actual code ;-) Maybe it is noteworthy that mongo and the client are version 3.2. Nevertheless, good luck.